# Convert/read dynamic array

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, dynamic, collections

I'm having to deal with a software's COM API. I need to read or convert a `dynamic` of type `Int[]` but any operation I try would return the error:

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32[*]' to type 'System32[]'.

I tried in many ways, here are some, but none works:

```
    int[] myint = (int[])mydynamic;
    int[] myint = mydynamic;
    string mystring String.Join(",", mydynamic);
    int[] myint = Convert.ToInt32(array);
    IEnumerable<int> myint  = array.Cast<int>();
```

If I stop the debugger I can see the content of mydynamic, but how can I read/convert it to another variable?

Comment: `Enumerable.Cast<int>`

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Comment: @PeterRitchie How should I use it? `Enumerable.Cast<int>(mydynamic);` returns the same error.. Thanks for your help.